# javascript transfer and element from 1 div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a tag filtering function in the website. The transferring from one div to another works. But transferring it back doesn't work.

This is my html:

```
<h4>Video Tags</h4>
<div id="tagbox-1">
     <span class="tag-filter">tag 1</span>
     <span class="tag-filter">tag 2</span>
     <span class="tag-filter">tag 3</span>
</div>
<h4>Video Filters</h4>
<div id="tagfilter-1">
</div>
```

Then this is my javascript/jquery:

```
function tag_ui_move(tag_object,filter_move_to){
    $(filter_move_to).append($(tag_object)).fadeIn();
    $(tag_object).remove();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stored_tag = [];
    $('[id^="tagbox-"] > span').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            tag_ui_move(this,'div[id^="tagfilter-"]');
        });
    });

    $('div[id^="tagfilter-"] > span').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            tag_ui_move(this,'div[id^="tagbox-"]');
        });
    });
});
```

This is pretty much the gist of my html and code. I simplified it because there are more tagbox- and tagfilter- divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$('[id^="tagbox-"] > span')` selects all of the tag span elements that exist in the tagbox *at that moment* and then you bind a click handler to each of them that moves it to the filter div. And then `$('div[id^="tagfilter-"] > span')` selects all of the tag span elements that exist in the filter div *at that moment* and *there aren't any.* So there is no handler bound to move the elements back.

Also there is no need to use an `.each()` loop to individually bind `.click()` to each element in the loop: you can just call `.click()` directly and it will bind the handler to all elements that matched your selector.

The solution is to use a delegated handler, where you use `.on()` to bind the click to the parent div elements but supply a secondary selector that jQuery will automatically test at the time the click event occurs:

```
function tag_ui_move(tag_object,filter_move_to){
    $(filter_move_to).append(tag_object).fadeIn();
    //$(tag_object).remove();  <-- commented out: don't remove the element,
                                 // because append *moves* it
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stored_tag = [];
    $('[id^="tagbox-"]').on('click', 'span.tag-filter', function(){
            tag_ui_move(this,'div[id^="tagfilter-"]');
    });

    $('div[id^="tagfilter-"]').on('click', 'span', function(){
        tag_ui_move(this,'div[id^="tagbox-"]');
    });
});
```

That way, when a click on any element within `'[id^="tagbox-"]'` occurs, jQuery tests if the target element matches the selector `'span.tag-filter'` and if and only if it does it calls your handler function. So then the clicks work on the elements even when they're dynamically moved back and forth between the two parent divs.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6m4aac3k/

Answer (score 0):

> HTML

```
<h4>Video Tags</h4>
<div id="tagbox">
     <span class="tag-filter">tag 1</span>
     <span class="tag-filter">tag 2</span>
     <span class="tag-filter">tag 3</span>
</div>
<h4>Video Filters</h4>
<div id="tagfilter">
</div>
```

> Javascript

```
function tag_ui_move(tag_object,filter_move_to){
    $(filter_move_to).append($(tag_object)).fadeIn();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tag-filter").click(function(){
        var  inTagBox=$(this).parent( "#tagbox" ).length>0;
        var moveTo=inTagBox ? '#tagfilter' : '#tagbox';
        tag_ui_move(this,moveTo);
    });
});
```

> JSFiddle

[Tag filter](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/yucpxjeL/)